# Will that 24Com be a C-Wire for HVAC?

Tags: hvac

I am not a technician and I am installing a Nest thermostat and couldn't find the C-wire.
On the Panel board, there is 24COM and the blue wire is not connected.
How do I test if this is a C-wire with 24 volt?

[image]

Comment: Gotta voltmeter?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

C-Wire stand for Common Wire. The B next to that stands for Blue, which is the standard color for a C-Wire. The 24COM terminal is almost certainly for the C-Wire, but you need a multimeter to make sure.  Set the multimeter to read AC voltage and check the voltage between the 24VAC (red wire) terminal and the 24COM terminal.  The voltage should be around 24 volts.